# Rails app: autoloading classes defined in modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, autoload

in Rails 5.0.1 application I have file *app/actions/frontend/cart/get_cart_items_summarized.rb* with:

```
module Actions
  module Frontend
    module Cart
      class GetCartItemsSummarized
        #content here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in *app/helpers/application_helper.rb* I call it:

```
def get_cart_items
  #...
  items = Actions::Frontend::Cart::GetCartItemsSummarized.new.call
  #...
end
```

But I'm getting:

*uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::Actions*

Why? How should I use this class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails/autoloading, the first level of directories, the one directly under `app`, is not considered a part of the name. It is so that your model can be just `User` and not `Models::User`, etc.

My solution to this is to put all custom stuff in `app/lib`. This way, `lib` eats that non-naming layer and the rest of your folder structure become a name. In your example, put your file to

```
app/lib/actions/frontend/cart/get_cart_items_summarized.rb
```

Of course, feel free to replace "lib" with whatever you want ("app/custom", for example). This name doesn't matter.

Comment: This looks like domain logic, so I would still keep it in `/app`.

Comment: @fylooi: keep it in `/app/domain` then ). To keep it separate from, say, views.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a full-qualified name:

```
::Actions::Frontend::Cart::GetCartItemsSummarized.new.call
```

or just stick to Rails constant lookup (the below should work):

```
GetCartItemsSummarized.new.call
```

Comment: Nah, FQN won't help.

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev - why not?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Huh? Of course when the class is defined as above FQN does work.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I don't think so. Your second example _might_ work. But first one won't. I'm willing to bet a beer on this.

Comment: @mudasobwa: it's not the class definition format. It's where its file is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you must be kidding. Rails [thanks God] still can’t affect the syntax Ruby classes are declared with. It might [or might not] have problems with loading, but once it’s loaded it’s definitely addressable as such.

Comment: @mudasobwa: ah, if we're talking eager loading, then yes. I was referring to auto-loading (which is used by default in dev mode)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I never could wrap my head around how it’s doing auto-loading, so I always just do plain old good `Dir.each(&:require)` :)

Answer (score 0):

In "config/application.rb", add "app" to autoload paths, e.g.:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

  config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app')]

end
```